# Problem in variable affectation in QtScript

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qtscript

I'm trying to get the result of a script simple operation on the C++ side.

I create a QScriptValue (myvar) and call `engine.globalObject().setProperty("result", myvar);`
Then I evaluate "result = anothervar + 7;" The evaluate method return value is OK but the variable result is not OK.
If the script is "result = anothervar + 7; a=1" then the result value is OK.

It looks too stupid to be a Qt bug so what did I miss ?

Thanks

Jeff

Comment: Works for me: `QScriptEngine e;
    e.globalObject().setProperty( "result", QScriptValue( 1.0 ) );
    e.globalObject().setProperty( "anotherVar", QScriptValue( 14 ) );
    const QScriptValue s = e.evaluate( "result = anotherVar + 7;" );
    qDebug() << s.toVariant();
    qDebug() << e.globalObject().property("result").toVariant();` both print "QVariant(double,21)".

Comment: Could you try to create a variable QScriptValue( 1.0 ) and display the value of this variable instead of reading the value in the engine ? (e.globalObject().property("result").toVariant()). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your answer to my comment, I'm assuming you're keeping the `QScriptValue myvar` instance around, and look at it after calling `evaluate()`:

```
QScriptEngine e;
QScriptValue myvar( 1.0 );
e.globalObject().setProperty( "result", myvar );
e.globalObject().setProperty( "anotherVar", QScriptValue( 14 ) );
const QScriptValue s = e.evaluate( "result = anotherVar + 7;" );
qDebug() << s.toVariant();
qDebug() << e.globalObject().property("result").toVariant();
qDebug() << myvar.toVariant();
```

This will print 2x "QVariant(double,21)" and once "QVariant(double,1)". That is expected behaviour, here's why:

In JavaScript, everything is an object, and you are only dealing with *references* to objects, not the objects themselves (if you know Java, this is similar to `int` vs. `Integer`). So, what the assignment `result = anotherVar + 7;` does is replace the object represented by `myvar` as the global object's "result" property with the object that results from the expression `anotherVar + 7`. Meanwhile, the QScriptValue `myvar` still references the (old) object, which otherwise would be up for grabs by the garbage-collecter at this point.

About the addition of `a=1` to fix the problem: I can't reproduce that here. The first debug statement prints the value of `a`, of course, but the second and third are unchanged.

The solution to your problem, therefore, is to always re-get the "result" property from the engine whenever you need it (using `engine.globalObject().property("result")`), or—in other words—QScriptValue doesn't track assigments.

If you *do* want to track assignment, you need to turn it into a method call: Implement `result` as a custom class with an `assign()` method, and replace assignment (`=`) with `result.assign( anotherVal + 7 );`.

Comment: You are right, a=1 does not fix anything, I should have dream this result !! I'm not sure to understand your explanation concerning "If you didn't hold on to the object represented by myvar through the QScriptValue myvar, then it would be garbage-collected at this point". What would be your advice to solve that problem ?

Comment: @JFM: I edited my answer to be (hopefully) more clear on both points.

Comment: OK, I was afraid of this answer... I have a lot of variables accessibles in many scripts but not all variables are modified in, all scripts. I wanted to avoid to get values for all variables. If I create a custom class replace QScriptValues will I get the same behaviour or can I expect to code a better feedback ? thru qScriptRegisterMetaType<MyClass>(&engine, toScriptValue, fromScriptValue); ?

Comment: @JFM: assignment always breaks the binding of the object to the name, so to say. Even if you implement the `result` object as you mention, this will still be the case. However, you can give that object an `assign()` (e.g.) method, and rewrite the JavaScript to say `result.assign( anotherVar + 7 );`. Then `result` will not be assigned-to and the QScriptValue will still reference the correct object, yes.